# Date Comparison - MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

In document there is date element like `doj:20100223` in YYYYMMDD format. I am looking for the query which display all records where doj>2010. Below i have tried but didn't work.

```
db.TestData1.aggregate(
     { $project : {name : 1 }},
     { $match : { doj : { $gt : 2010}}}
)
```

Any suggestion..

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Since your data appears to be stored in an integer field, your query should look like :

```
db.TestData1.aggregate(
     { $match : { doj : { $gt : 20109999}}},
     { $project : {name : 1 }}
)
```

Beware the `$project` operator reshapes every record, so you need to either include the doj field you want to query here, or move it after the `$match` in the pipeline.